# Generate modal with JS containing a Router - laravel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

```js
function confirmDelete(ruta, id){
            alert(ruta +","+ id);
            document.getElementById('confirmDeleteModal').innerHTML = '<div class="modal-dialog max-w-2xl">'
                + '<div class="modal-content mx-auto">'
                    + '<div class="modal-header">'
                        + '<button type="button" class="close la la-times" data-dismiss="modal"></button>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '<div class="modal-body">'
                        + '<h2>¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el registro?</h2>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '<div class="modal-footer">'
                        + '<div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2">'
                            
                                + '<a  href="{{route('+ ruta +', '+ id +'}}"'
                                    + 'class="btn btn_primary">'
                                    + 'Aceptar'
                                + '</a>'
                            + '<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal"'
                                + 'class="btn btn_outlined btn_secondary uppercase">Cancelar</button>'
                        + '</div>'
                    + '</div>'
                + '</div>'
            +'</div>';
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="confirmDelete('method.tables.bank-entities.delete','1')" class="btn btn-icon btn_outlined btn_secondary">
  eliminar
</a>
<div id="createModal" class="modal" data-animations="fadeInDown, fadeOutUp">
</div>
```

I have an anchor that executes a function to remove

```
<a onclick="confirmDelete('method.tables.bank-entities.delete','1')"
                                    class="btn btn-icon btn_outlined btn_secondary">
                                    <span class="la la-trash"></span>
                                </a>
```

This function adds the content to a modal
The function needs 2 parameters the route and the id to delete

```
    function confirmDelete(ruta, id){
        alert(ruta +","+ id);
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't add the content to the div of the modal and I don't know how to use the "{{route('+ route +', '+ id +'}}" in js

Comment: You are giving wrong modal id in document.getElementById('confirmDeleteModal').innerHTML.

You have to change confirmDeleteModal to createModal.

Comment: The modal if it was solved correctly now the problem is how can I add the router to the href

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, what you want is to use a Laravel function (route) but passing the values through javascript, however that is not possible. First the laravel code is executed on the server and the generated result (html and JS) is sent to the client, so you can't call laravel functions directly from javascript.

One way to solve this would be to create your route string using javascript from the received data, without using Laravel code.

```
+ '<a  href="http:/example.com/'+ ruta +'/'+ id +'"'
     + 'class="btn btn_primary">'
     + 'Aceptar'
     + '</a>'
```